# Add an existing function to a class as a static method (javascript / es6)

Tags: javascript

I'd like to take an existing function

```
const fn = () => console.log('fn')
```

and add it to an existing class

```
class Foo { }
```

as a *static* method, so that

```
Foo.fn() // console prints 'fn'
```

Is this possible ?
Something like

```
class Foo { static fn = fn }
```

throws...

Comment: You can set it as `Foo.prototype.fn = fn` an then call it using Foo.fn()

Comment: @PedroSturmer `Foo.fn = fn` prototype is for instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do something like this

```js
const fn = () => console.log('fn')


class Foo { }

Foo.fn = fn;

Foo.fn() // console prints 'fn'
```